# exportfs with rw not working , fstab either. Mount point still read only on my setup machine

Tags: centos, mount, read-only

I have a VM that other VMs and servers mount from.   This vm has an ip of say:

10.10.1.1

The folder that others mount is \export\images

So one VM mounts this in its fstab:

10.10.1.1:/export/images      /export/images          nfs     rsize=32768,wsize=32768,actimeo=0,bg,intr

Great anything that has this in their FSTAB (os's I didn't build) can read and write to this directory all day!

A new PC I set up couldn't so I thought I also had to edit the 'servers' VM /etc/exports(which is sim linked for some reason? I didn't set this machine up)

It has the right line:

/export/images  10.22.1.93(rw)

That 10.22.1.93 is a server I set up.  Which has the fstab entry:

10.10.1.1:/export/images      /export/images          nfs     rsize=32768,wsize=32768,actimeo=0,bg,intr

This server I set up, if I do a mount -a it mounts everything from FSTAB and I goto /export/images and then try to touch a file and it says cannot 'Read-Only file system'.

I even unmount and do a mount -a as root again.

On the 'server' I did exportfs -a before trying all this.  Still no go, do I have to reset my newly setup PC to get it to take?  As far as I can tell this 'should be' letting my new machine read/write to the mount from its fstab .

Comment: does `showmount -e 10.10.1.1` from the client show what you would expect?  Have you tried `exportfs -rav` on the server to clear old settings just in case?